# Search for number in a text file?

Tags: python, regex, text-processing, text-parsing

I try to get a number from my logfile. This number comes after every "current store usage is ". How can I do that? Can I use the `re` module?

**Line from the logfile**

```
2017-05-30 12:01:03,168 | WARN  | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/apache-activemq-5.12.0/bin/linux-x86-64/../../data only has 6887 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: 6887 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain
```

**My code**

```
def log_parser():
    palab2 = "WARN"
    logfile = open("/opt/apache-activemq-5.12.0/data/activemq.log", "r")
    contenlog = logfile.readlines()
    logfile.close()
    for ligne in contenlog:
        if palab2 in ligne:
            print ("Probleme : " + ligne)
```

Comment: Don't read the whole file with `readlines`. You can iterate over each line. And yes, you can use `re`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `re` module to greatly simplify this. And +1 to [@Eric Duminil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6419007/eric-duminil) for the suggestion to not read in the entire file at once.

```
import re

def log_parser():
    palab2 = "WARN"
    logfile = "/opt/apache-activemq-5.12.0/data/activemq.log"

    with open(logfile, 'r') as contenlog:
        for ligne in contenlog:
            if re.findall(palab2, ligne):
                print ("Probleme : " + ligne)
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work for you:

```
import re
ligne  = '2017-05-30 12:01:03,168 | WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/apache-activemq-5.12.0/bin/linux-x86-64/../../data only has 6887 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: 6887 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | WrapperSimpleAppMain'
print(re.search(r'current store usage is (\d+)', ligne).group(1))
# this returns a 'string', you can convert it to 'int'
```

Output:

```
'0'
```

Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

def log_parser():
    with open("/opt/apache-activemq-5.12.0/data/activemq.log", "r") as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            m = re.search(r"current store usage is (\d+)", line):
                if m:
                    return m.group(1)

print(log_parser())
```

You didn't specify if you want just the first occurence (I assumed so) or all such lines in the file. If the latter is true, just change `return` to `yield` and then call the function like this: `print(list(log_parser()))`